# XGBoost Loss not changing with HyperOpt

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost, hyperopt

I'm trying to optimize the hyperparameters on my XGBoost model using HyperOpt, but the loss is not changing with every iteration. You can find my code below:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=random_state)

space={'max_depth': hp.quniform("max_depth", 3, 18, 1),
        'gamma': hp.uniform ('gamma', 1,9),
        'reg_alpha' : hp.quniform('reg_alpha', 40,180,1),
        'reg_lambda' : hp.uniform('reg_lambda', 0,1),
        'colsample_bytree' : hp.uniform('colsample_bytree', 0.5,1),
        'min_child_weight' : hp.quniform('min_child_weight', 0, 10, 1),
        'learning_rate': hp.uniform('learning_rate', 0, 1),
        'n_estimators': 100000,
        'seed': random_state
    }

def objective(space):
    clf=xgb.XGBClassifier(
                    n_estimators =space['n_estimators'], max_depth = int(space['max_depth']), gamma = space['gamma'],
                    reg_alpha = int(space['reg_alpha']),min_child_weight=int(space['min_child_weight']),
                    colsample_bytree=int(space['colsample_bytree']))
    
    evaluation = [( X_train, y_train), ( X_test, y_test)]
    
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train,
            eval_set=evaluation, eval_metric="auc",
            early_stopping_rounds=10,verbose=False)

    pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = f1_score(y_test, pred>0.5)
    print ("SCORE:", accuracy)
    return {'loss': 1-accuracy, 'status': STATUS_OK }

trials = Trials()

best_hyperparams = fmin(fn = objective,
                        space = space,
                        algo = tpe.suggest,
                        max_evals = 1000,
                        trials = trials)
```

After running this code, the score doesn't change. The output is shown below:

```
SCORE:                                                                            
0.8741788782213239                                                                
SCORE:                                                                            
0.8741788782213239                                                                
SCORE:                                                                            
0.8741788782213239                                                                
SCORE:                                                                            
0.8741788782213239                                                                
SCORE:                                                                            
0.8741788782213239                                                                
SCORE:                                                                            
0.8741788782213239                                                                
SCORE:                                                                            
0.8741788782213239                                                                
SCORE:                                                                            
0.8741788782213239                                                                
100%|██████████| 100/100 [00:21<00:00,  4.57trial/s, best loss: 0.1258211217786761]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are converting the parameters to int and hence you are getting the same loss. For example `colsample_bytree=int(space['colsample_bytree'])` will always be zero because of `int()` so to solve your question don't convert float parameters to int.

```
clf=xgb.XGBClassifier(
                    n_estimators =space['n_estimators'], max_depth = int(space['max_depth']), 
                    gamma = space['gamma'], reg_alpha = int(space['reg_alpha']),
                    min_child_weight=space['min_child_weight'],
                    colsample_bytree=space['colsample_bytree'])
```

Note: Int is required for n_estimators, max_depth and reg_alpha

Comment: This remains unsolved. Anyone with a solution?

Comment: How doo you know? Has the op left any comment?